# Problem in Publishing page and web part page in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, publishing-page, web-part-page

I have created one module in my solution which is add in **_catalogs/masterpage** on feature activation. The module which I have created in that there is a **Publishing page** which is set as a Home page of the site. The problem is that if  I add publishing page then it will disabled all the controls of the ribbon row. I am able to get ribbon controls in all other publishing pages.

[image]

I have also tried for **web part page**. but in this case I have put one **Content query web part** in web part page. I have tried for same thing for web part page also but problem is that I have put only one **content query web part** on page then also it will display two times on page.

[image]

how should I make one of these page as a Home page without an any issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your web parts will be put as many times as your feature activation. That's driving so many people crazy. Checkout the workaround by Waldek:

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/preventing-provisioning-duplicate-web-parts-instances-on-feature-reactivation/